# Uniqueness of solutions to elliptic PDE in $W^{1,1}$

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations, elliptic-equations

Consider for definiteness the elliptic problem
$$-\nabla \cdot a(x) \nabla u(x) = 0, x \in \Omega$$
with boundary conditions $u|_{\partial \Omega} =0 $, where $\Omega$ is some bounded $C^1$ domain in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $a \in L^\infty(\Omega).$ The usual results says the only solution in $H^1(\Omega)$ is the zero function. More generally though, we can interpret the above equation distributionally for $u \in W^{1,1}(\Omega)$. The question then is whether there exists a non-zero solution to the above problem for $u \in W^{1,1}_0(\Omega)$?

This question can be thought of as asking for a "true" uniqueness result for elliptic problems. $W^{1,1}(\Omega)$ is the largest space which (to me at least) allows a natural interpretation of the above boundary value problem, hence is a natural setting for asking the question of uniqueness.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem above does not have a unique solution in $W^{1,1}(\Omega)$. A non-trivial solution was given by James Serrin in [A] (below).

There is an extensive theory of existence, uniqueness and non-uniqueness of weak solutions for the corresponding non-homogeneous problem: $$(*)\qquad \qquad -\mathrm{div}(a \nabla u)=f,$$ which can help understand why the problem is not an easy one. The source $f$ is usually chosen in Lebesgue spaces ($L^p$) or Marcinkiewicz spaces ($L^{p,\infty}$). Marcinkiewicz spaces are occasionally considered more natural, since the fundamental solution to $\Delta u = \delta_0$ ($n\geq 3$) has characteristic growth in a Marcinkiewicz space, but not in any Lebesgue space.

It turns out that the uniqueness of solutions to $(*)$ can fail depending on the summability of $f$. For example:

> for every $1\leq m\leq n/2$ there exists a distributional (duality with $\mathcal C_0^\infty(\Omega)$) solution to $(*)$ satisfying $u\in L^{m^{**}}$ and $|\nabla u|\in L^{m^*}$, but this solution is unique only if $m> (2^*)'$ (Hölder conjugate of the Sobolev exponent $2^*$), in which case one additionally has that $u\in W^{1,2}_0$. (For $m> n/2$ one has directly $u\in W^{1,2}_0\cap L^\infty$.)

This problem led to the introduction of so-called *SOLAs* (Solutions Obtained as Limits of Approximations). Indeed, it turns out that the solution operator to $(*)$ mapping the source $f$ to the corresponding unique solution $u$ (for $m>(2^*)'$) is continuous even below the critical threshold $(2^*)'$, and thus one can show that SOLAs are unique:

> if $f_n\in L^\infty$ $L^m$-converges to $f\in L^{m}$ ($1<m<(2^*)'$), then the corresponding solutions $u_n$ $L^{m^{**}}$-converges to the unique SOLA $u$ to $(*)$ with source $f$.

The other possible solutions to $(*)$ with source $f$ are thus “inaccessible“ by source regularization.

[A] Serrin, James, *Pathological solutions of elliptic differential equations*, Annali della Scuola Normale di Pisa – Classe di Scienze, 3rd series, vol. 18 (1964), pages 385-387

Comment: Cool. I didn't ask the non-homogenous question because uniqueness can be reduced to the homogenous case. Another case in analysis where there are nasty pathological examples lurking right outside the "nice" cases. Interesting that we can get existence in the non-homogenous case with poor(er) integrability to the source term though.

Comment: @PhysicalMathematics In fact, Serrin's example is not at all pathological: If I remember correctly, when $\Omega$ is the unit disk (maybe), $a_{ij}=\delta_{ij}+a x_ix_j/|x|^2$, and the non-trivial solution is $u=x_1 |x|^{1-n-c}$ where the parameter $c>0$ is uniquely determined as a function of the parameter $a>0$. The pathologies arise from the failure of some dualities between Sobolev spaces (these can be understood by looking at the exponents for the solutions in the non-homogeneous case, which is why I thought it was instructive). There are all kinds of other interesting phenomena...

Comment: For instance, adding additional lower order terms can increase the regularity of the solution. Sorry, I forgot to point out references! Some contributors are e.g. Bernard Dacorogna, Haïm Brezis, Lucio Boccardo and many many others. If memory serves well, SOLAs have been introduced by Boccardo, Luigi Orsina and coauthors. There is a nice booklet by [Boccardo&Croce](https://www.degruyter.com/document/doi/10.1515/9783110315424/html). For Marcinkiewicz spaces see e.g. [here](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2Fs40574-015-0028-y) for a partial summary of the results and where to find them.